# Regular expression for media queries in CSS

Tags: php, regex, styles, media-queries

I'm searching for a way to extract media queries from a CSS file.

```
/* "normal" css selectors

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:auto;-ms-text-size-adjust:auto;}
    img {max-width: 100% !important; 
         height: auto !important; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    .content{ 
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

now I like to get only the media queries. I though the begin is always `@media` and the end of the search is always a curly bracket followed by some optional whitespace and another curly bracket.

The only thing I have is

```
preg_match_all('#@media ?[^{]+?{XXX#',$stylesheetstring, $result);
```

were `XXX` is the missing part I'm searching for.

The current one (without the X) only returns the first line (obviously)

Comment: Could you prepare a demo on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) or [codepad.org](http://codepad.org)?

Comment: Do you want the entire css block, or just the line that starts with `@media`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want the entire media block, I don't think this is the right job for regex.

You could however, implement a simple parsing function:

```
function parseMediaBlocks($css)
{
    $mediaBlocks = array();

    $start = 0;
    while (($start = strpos($css, "@media", $start)) !== false)
    {
        // stack to manage brackets
        $s = array();

        // get the first opening bracket
        $i = strpos($css, "{", $start);

        // if $i is false, then there is probably a css syntax error
        if ($i !== false)
        {
            // push bracket onto stack
            array_push($s, $css[$i]);

            // move past first bracket
            $i++;

            while (!empty($s))
            {
                // if the character is an opening bracket, push it onto the stack, otherwise pop the stack
                if ($css[$i] == "{")
                {
                    array_push($s, "{");
                }
                elseif ($css[$i] == "}")
                {
                    array_pop($s);
                }

                $i++;
            }

            // cut the media block out of the css and store
            $mediaBlocks[] = substr($css, $start, ($i + 1) - $start);

            // set the new $start to the end of the block
            $start = $i;
        }
    }

    return $mediaBlocks;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick and is slightly faster than `preg_match_all`