# Regex parsing of CSS @media queries (and other nested selectors)

Tags: javascript, css, regex, node.js

I'm working on a node script which uses regex to parse CSS files, and it works perfectly... except when dealing with @media queries. The problem is due to the nested curly-brackets which are giving me fits. I essentially want to create a capturing group of ALL the content inside a media query: Here's what I've got so far.

`@media[^{]+\{([^}]+)}\s*}`

This works fine on something simple like:

```
@media (max-width: 868px) {
  aside .size-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But can't pick up multiple nested rules, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #wrapper.sidebar-display aside {
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  #wrapper.sidebar-display #top-nav {
    left: 0;
    right: -194px;
  }
}
```

How do I need to modify my regex so that the capturing group contains all the selectors and rules inside each individual @media query?

Comment: What language / platform are you using?

Comment: This sounds very dangerous. How does your parser handle internet explorer specific image filters? They have very different patterns that is common in CSS and might easily break a parser.

Comment: It's javascript running on node. It handles IE specific crap just fine as far as I can tell. The code uses a `([^@{}]+)}` to capture the entire content of each selector and then each rule gets broken up into essentially key/value pairs based off the `:`. It's the double { that causes it to break down in the case of media queries which is what I need help with. My plan is to capture the entire content of the media query and then run that content through the regular portion of the script, essentially treating it as a self contained CSS file.

Comment: See this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145620/regular-expression-for-media-queries-in-css?rq=1 The answer is written in PHP, but it should be easy to port to JS.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. While it's obviously doable that method, it breaks the clean parsing model I was using (based off `.replace()` with a callback function). It feels like this ought to be possible in regex, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Your question lacks a context of what exactly you want to achieve, but usually it's a bad idea to write your own "parser" with regex. You should probably use some mature modules like [css-parse](https://github.com/reworkcss/css-parse) instead.

Comment: It's not just media queries that break your regex. 1) Many more at-rules have nested curly braces; @keyframes, @page etc. 2) Also, selectors as well as property values can contain braces. E.G. `[title='{}']::before {content:'{}';}`. Your parser should take those into account.

Comment: @lukaszfiszer: I'm parsing CSS to convert it into Jade.

Comment: @MrLister: Yeah, I figured all the nested at-rules would work exactly the same way, I just started with `@media` first. I hadn't thought about selectors which could contain curly braces, but frankly that's a pretty fringe case so I'm not too concerned with it currently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/@media[^{]+\{([\s\S]+?})\s*}/g
```

**Demo**
http://regex101.com/r/iT2eR5/1

Comment: above regex is not handling all cases. It is failing if there are multi nested open brackers.

Comment: @SumitSharma Please check updated link in answer.

Comment: I have add the case in the demo link where the mentioned regex wont work. Please check.

Comment: @SumitSharma Which version ? (https://regex101.com/r/iT2eR5/???)